# Draw a checker pattern with a black X in the center

Tags: tikz-pgf, code-review

I am trying to recreate the following image in Ti*k*Z

[image]

Using some old code I was able to produce the following result

[image]

While I was able to produce the correct result, I feel that my solution was a bit strange as it required two passes. Any suggestions for alternative approaches, or improvements to the code are more than welcome.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
\edef\size{4}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,\size} \foreach \y in {0,...,\size}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,\size) ? "none" : "black"}
        \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
        \path[draw=black, fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);

        \pgfmathparse{\x==\y ? "black" : "none"}
        \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
        \path[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    }
    \draw (0,0)--(0,\size+1)--(\size+1,\size+1)--(\size+1,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum size=10mm, fill=black,
                 outer sep=0pt},
                      ]
\edef\size{4}
\foreach \y in {0,...,\size}
\foreach \x in {0,...,\size}
{\ifnum\x=\y
\node[box]   at (\x,\size-\y) {};
\node[box]   at (\x,\y) {};
 \else
\node[box,fill=none] at (\x,\y) {};
 \fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** Value of `\size` had to be zero or any even natural number (0, 2, 4, ...)

**addendum:**

- default baseline of above image is as `(current bounding box.south)˙ For series of those images for different value of`size` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C C >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.south),
node distance = 0mm,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum size=10mm, fill=black,
                 outer sep=0pt},
                      ]
\edef\size{0} % in this MWE the meaning of `\size` is changed
\foreach \y in {0,...,\size}
\foreach \x in {0,...,\size}
{\ifnum\x=\y
\node[box]   at (\x,\size-\y) {};
\node[box]   at (\x,\y) {};
 \else
\node[box,fill=none] at (\x,\y) {};
 \fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
&
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%baseline=(current bounding box.south),
node distance = 0mm,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum size=10mm, fill=black,
                 outer sep=0pt},
                      ]
\edef\size{1}
\foreach \y in {0,...,2*\size} % changed, now number of boxes is odd 
\foreach \x in {0,...,2*\size} % changed,
{\ifnum\x=\y
\node[box]   at (\x,\size-\y) {};
\node[box]   at (\x,\y) {};
 \else
\node[box,fill=none] at (\x,\y) {};
 \fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
&
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.south),
node distance = 0mm,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum size=10mm, fill=black,
                 outer sep=0pt},
                      ]
\edef\size{2}
\foreach \y in {0,...,\size}
\foreach \x in {0,...,\size}
{\ifnum\x=\y
\node[box]   at (\x,\size-\y) {};
\node[box]   at (\x,\y) {};
 \else
\node[box,fill=none] at (\x,\y) {};
 \fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can this produce the correct case with only one black box?

Comment: With `\edef\size{1}`? I'm not sure if I understood your comment correctly.

Comment: `\size{1}` produces 4 black squares not 1. Here is how it looks for n=1 and n=2, not the same baseheight either. https://i.imgur.com/0OamEbM.png

Comment: Indeed. It should be `\size{0}`.

Comment: Great (I was sure `\size{0}` gave me an error). Any idea how to fix it so that the figures have the same baseline? See https://i.imgur.com/OFgcE96.png

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, images are aligned to their bottom side. also see "Note" in edited answer.

Comment: How can I change the size to a rectangular one, e.g. checker box with 2 vertical squares and 5 horizontal squares?

Comment: @pankajsingh, sorry, I do not understand your comment. It be better, if you ask new question, which will be visible to all members of site. In it provide what you try so far and show a sketch, what you like to have.

Comment: I want to make a rectangular checker box (not a square one). How can I do that?

Comment: @pankajsingh, please ask a new question. Only I am aware of your comment, therefore other people are not in position to help you. BTW, if you not like a squares, just replace them with rectangles by defining `minimum width` and `minimum height`. For more, let repeat me, ask new question, where you show, what you tray yourself and where you stuck. I can't provide an answer in comment. So, let me say again, ask new question.

Answer (score 10):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes!

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\obj#1{%
    \pspicture[dimen=m](#1,#1)
        \multips(0,0)(0,1){#1}{\multips(0,0)(1,0){#1}{\psframe(1,1)}}
        \multips(0,0)(1,1){#1}{\psframe*(1,1)}
        \multips(0,#1)(1,-1){#1}{\psframe*(1,-1)}
    \endpspicture}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {3,5,7}{\obj{\i}\quad}
\end{document}
```

## Edit

I invented the algorithm (that has not been patented yet) as follows. No nested loop is needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=5mm}
\def\obj#1{%
    \pspicture[dimen=m](#1,#1)
    \FPeval\N{#1*#1-1}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\N}
    {
        \FPeval\y{trunc(\j/#1:0)}
        \FPeval\x{\j-#1*y}
        \xintifboolexpr{\x=\y||(\x+\y)=(#1-1)}
        {\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black](\x,\y)(+\x+1,\y+1)}
        {\psframe(\x,\y)(+\x+1,\y+1)}
    }
    \endpspicture}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,3,5,7,9}{\obj{\i}\quad}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One downvote detected...

Comment: Accessing 2 dimensional arrays with a single-indexed pointer is much faster.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:**
The following works for all values of `size`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\size{4}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,\size} \foreach \y in {0,...,\size} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\colour}{(\x==\y || \x+\y==\size) ? "black" : "none"}
        \draw[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can this produce the correct case with only one black box?

Comment: The `mod` function was not a good choice, `\pgfmathparse{\x+\y==\size ? "black" : "\colour"}` is better.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the reason for a double loop, nor complicated conditions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xboard/.style={insert path={
(0,0) grid (#1,#1)
foreach \X in {1,...,#1}
{(\X-0.5,\X-0.5) pic{bx} (\X-0.5,#1-\X+0.5) pic{bx}}}},
pics/bx/.style={code={\fill (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);}}]
\draw[xboard=1] [xshift=2cm,xboard=3]
[xshift=4cm,xboard=5] [xshift=6cm,xboard=7];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]